# Unable to fix how much list a combobox may contains.

Tags: java, memory, javafx, combobox

I am using comboBox in javaFX through Scene Builder

```
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> pageNoComboBox;
```

Now i am processing large no of list and sets in ComboBox.

```
    Common.totalPageOnCashBook=(val%50==0)? val/50 : val/50 +1;
    for(int count=1;count<=Common.totalPageOnCashBook;count++)
    {
        this.pageCombo.getItems().add(String.valueOf(count));
    }
```

In case of small data it works fine.But in case of large data (say 1m).It throws below warnings on console.

```
 Mar 10, 2016 9:53:21 AM com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.
 VirtualFlow addTrailingCells
 INFO: index exceeds maxCellCount. Check size calculations
 for class com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin$4$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check javadoc reference from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html).But according to me it should be quite enough to point a comboBox to something (val%50).